# sed alternative to non-greedy searching

Tags: regex, linux, sed

Well, I know sed doesn't support non-greedy searching but is there maybe a clever regex to replace the following

```
VARIABLE="
text1
text2
text3
"
```

with

```
VARIABLE="
Atext1
Atext2
Atext3
"
```

Right now I'm only able to replace the first match.

Comment: `sed 's/text/Atext/g'` doesn't work?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Sorry, it's just a bad example that I gave. The variables could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe in this case it matters that sed does not support non-greedy regex, a non-inclusive range-replacement such as the below should suffice. I ran a test with GNU sed, see results below

```
sed '/^VAR.*="/,/^"/ {/"/! s/^/A/}' testfile.txt
VARIABLE="
Atext1
Atext2
Atext3
"
test
data
test
p
VARIABLE="
Atext1
Atext2
Atext3
"
test
data
```

EDIT: Or as [Potong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/967492/potong) points out, this can be reduced to the more idiomatic form

```
sed '/^VAR.*="/,/^"/ {//! s/^/A/}' testfile.txt
```

Comment: This might be shortened slightly to `sed '/^VAR.*="/,/^"/ {//! s/^/A/}'`

Comment: @potong, thank you, that is indeed more idiomatic, I have edited my answer

Comment: @potong Can you please explain how the `//` matches here?

Comment: @Sparhawk `//` means use the last regexp provided. In this case either of the addresses used in the flip-flop command. So the `A` is only inserted between the first and second addresses.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the text does not contains double quotes:

```
sed '/"/!s/^/A/' input
```

Comment: Good answer. But I forgot to mention that the input text could contain additional text along with the specified.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to replace the contents of the variable:

```
VARIABLE=$(sed 's/./A&/' <<< "$VARIABLE")
```